# Unable to import packages in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, fscalendar

I am currently trying to import the FSCalendar package into Xcode. The link is: https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar. I'm using the package manager (file -> add packages -> plus button in bottom left corner -> add package collection...). Upon entering the link, I receive the error: <Received invalid response at https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar. Please make sure it is a package collection URL.>. I have a Github, with an ssh key. I know the ssh key works for my mac, because I am able to push changes to a different project I'm working on. Does anyone know what's causing this?

I've tried manually setting my private ssh key path as well as uninstalling and reinstalling xcode.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't try adding a package collection. Instead, paste the URL into the top right search bar after going to `File -> add packages`, then select the package, select the Project you want to add the dependency to and tap Add package.

[image: Xcode screenshot]

If the search returns no results, you might have to add the `.git` suffix to the URL, that should solve the issue.

So use

https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar.git

instead of

https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar